# Not able to integrate Spring HATEOAS in my existing Spring Boot REST API

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-rest, spring-hateoas

**Exception**

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.Path
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.springframework.hateoas.jaxrs.JaxRsLinkBuilder.<clinit>(JaxRsLinkBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-hateoas-0.23.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at com.study.rest.controller.ProductController.getAllProducts(ProductController.java:50) ~[classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE
]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELE
ASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]

2017-09-25 17:15:17.104  INFO 4032 --- [       Thread-7] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6cd378ed: startup date
[Mon Sep 25 17:13:31 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
```

I am seeing above exception when hitting my REST API for getting all products. Here is my controller class.

**ProductController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ProductController {

    @Inject
    private ProductService productService;

    //READ ALL
    //URI: http://localhost:8080/api/products
    @RequestMapping(value = "/products", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Iterable<Product>> getAllProducts() {
        Iterable<Product> products = productService.getAllProducts();
        //building hypermedia links here
        for (Product product : products) {
            Link selfLink = linkTo(ProductController.class).slash(product.getProductId()).withSelfRel();
            product.add(selfLink);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(products, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

      //code removed for brevity
}
```

**Product.java**

```
@Entity
public class Product extends ResourceSupport {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
    private Long id;

  //code removed for brevity

}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30227261/5873923). And please provide your full configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add next dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```